Mockito not able to mock Room Dao Class?
I have the following code to try and test my AppRepository class:
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
@MediumTest
class AppRepositoryTest {
    @Mock private lateinit var counterDao: CounterDao
    @Mock private lateinit var projectDao: ProjectDao
    private lateinit var appRepository: AppRepository

// region Setup and Teardown

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        counterDao = mock(CounterDao::class.java)
        appRepository = AppRepository(counterDao = counterDao, projectDao = projectDao)

        `when`(counterDao.insertCounter(TestData.validCounter)).thenReturn(1L)

        val test = counterDao.insertCounter(TestData.validCounter)

        println(test)
    }

// code
}

However, I get the following error:
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException:
Mockito cannot mock this class: interface com.sycosoft.jkc.database.dao.CounterDao.

Mockito can only mock non-private & non-final classes, but the root cause of this error 
might be different.
Please check the full stacktrace to understand what the issue is.
If you're still not sure why you're getting this error, please open an issue on GitHub.

I can see that it says that Mockito can only mock non-private and non-final classes, however, I've tried using mockito-inline which I've read allows the mocking of final classes and it comes out with the same error.
Here's what I have code wise for the Dao:
@Dao 
interface CounterDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM table_counters")
    fun getAllCounters(): List<Counter>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM table_counters WHERE owning_part_id = :projectId")
    fun getPartCounters(projectId: Long): List<Counter>

    @Insert
    fun insertCounter(counter: Counter): Long

    @Query("DELETE FROM table_counters WHERE id = :id")
    fun deleteCounterById(id: Long)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM table_counters WHERE id = :id")
    fun getCounterById(id: Long): Counter?

    @Query("DELETE FROM table_counters")
    fun deleteAllCounters()

}

So my question is, how do I go about using Mockito to mock the counterDao/projectDao in order to be able to test my AppRepository?
Thanks.

Please post the entire stack trace
